# Understanding Camtasia Studio Hexadecimal Data

Tags: windows, hex

Camtasia Studio is a software package for recording screen captures. One thing it does, it records the mouse movement coordinates separately from the video of your screen. It does this so you can modify the appearance of the cursor after you are done recording.

Once you have recorded your screen, it has an option for exporting the raw components of your capture. One of the files contains the cursor coordinates which look like this...

```
4556 5453 0300 0000 0c00 0000 0c00 0000
ca00 0000 0c00 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000
8002 0000 e001 0000 1900 0000 cb00 0000
1900 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 000c 0259
0000 0059 0014 0000 00e0 e8ab 096a 032d
08b8 0100 00c8 0000 0008 0000 0037 0000
00b0 feff ffef 0328 02d2 0100 00f0 0328
02d2 0100 00f1 0329 02e0 0100 00f2 032a
02e0 0100 00f5 032b 02ed 0100 00f8 032d
02ed 0100 00fb 032f 02fa 0100 0001 0432
02fa 0100 0007 0435 0208 0200 000e 043a
0208 0200 0018 043f 0215 0200 0023 0445
0215 0200 002e 044a 0215 0200 0039 0450
0215 0200 0046 0455 0215 0200 004f 0458
0215 0200 0056 045a 022c 0200 005d 045e
022c 0200 0063 0462 0242 0200 0068 0465
0242 0200 006f 046b 0258 0200 0072 046f
0258 0200 0079 0476 0280 0200 0082 047d
0280 0200 0089 0484 028c 0200 0091 048a
028c 0200 0098 0494 029a 0200 009e 049c
029a 0200 00a3 04a0 029a 0200 00a7 04a3
029a 0200 00aa 04a6 02aa 0200 00af 04ab
02bc 0200 00b2 04ae 02bc 0200 00b4 04b3
02bc 0200 00b8 04b7 02cc 0200 00be 04bd
02cc 0200 00c1 04bf 02dd 0200 00c3 04c1
02dd 0200 00c6 04c4 02f8 0200 00c9 04c6
02f8 0200 00cb 04c8 0205 0300 00cc 04c9
0213 0300 00cd 04c9 0213 0300 00cd 04ca
0220 0300 00ce 04cb 0221 0300 00ce 04cc
0221 0300 00ce 04cd 0236 0300 00ce 04ce
0236 0300 00cd 04cf 024d 0300 00cc 04d0
024d 0300 00cc 04d1 0262 0300 00cb 04d2
0262 0300 00cb 04d3 0279 0300 00ca 04d3
02a5 0300 00c9 04d3 0218 0000 0002 0000
000c 0000 0002 0000 0000 0000 0081 0404
0487 06a5 04a5 0300 00f8 0304 0487 06ba
040a 0000 0003 0000 000a 0000 0001 0000
0000 0000 0000 0008 0009 000c 0000 0001
0000 000c 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 00ff
033b 027f 061b 040c 0000 0005 0000 000c
0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00ff
ffff ff0c 0000 0004 0000 000c 0000 0001
0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 001c
0000 002d 0100 001c 0000 0001 0000 0090
0300 0000 0100 0079 0000 0044 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00
```

This is from a 1 second recording. The screen capture size was 640x480. I was moving the mouse from the top left corner to the bottom right corner.

So here is my question. Is there a way to translate this information to time and X, Y coordinates of the video? I guess I just don't understand the notation but I want to use this information for my own project. Can anyone make sense of this data?